# Best way to clean car carpet?

Tags: smell

If you have a damp and musky carpet what is the best way to clean it? I imagine it’s too big to be put in a washing machine.

I guess you could put it in a bath tub and agitate but I hope there’s another way.

If your going to suggest just shampooing and rinsing it isn’t that going to just get to the surfaces and hence your smell will still be there at lower amounts?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the carpet from car and then power wash it. You can use soap and brush to scrub it if power washing is not enough and then let it dry by leaving it in sun.

This is how most detailers I have seen do it for the car lots before putting the car out on the lot for sale.